# I want PHP to buffer my MySQL results client-side AND I want to begin using the results immediately

Tags: php, mysql, buffered, unbuffered

Do MySQL unbuffered queries really use no PHP buffering at all? And do buffered queries really buffer the whole result set before PHP has access to the data?

From what I've read about MySQL buffered queries, this isn't what I want because I want to start working on the results right away and not have to wait for all of the results to be buffered before I begin. But from what I've read about unbuffered queries, this isn't what I want either because I do want it to buffer the results on the client so that MySQL isn't being held up longer than it has to, I just don't want it to wait for the results to be fully buffered before I can begin working on the results. So help me understand.

Do buffered queries in MySQL/PHP really buffer the whole result set before PHP is allowed to begin using the results? And do unbuffered queries really use no buffering at all so that MySQL server is constantly waiting for PHP to request the next result before it is sent to the client? If this is true, why isn't there a way to begin using the results immediately and yet still buffer the results to take the load off of MySQL?

My MySQL server is a shared server with many different client nodes. So it doesn't make sense to not use buffering on the client side. But the queries are large and so they shouldn't need to wait for the whole result set to be returned to begin using the result.

So do I understand this right? There's no way to do what I want here? There's no way to handle this in a practical way?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php 99.9% of people have no issue with the buffered default. you are over thinking this. you would have to be doing something unique to no stick to the default

Comment: Most people don't query thousands of rows with no limit. If I were just expecting a few results, the default of waiting for the entire result set before being able to proceed would be fine. I'm sure what I'm doing is not unique though which is why I think it's a question worth asking.

Comment: if you have a specific scenario, please provide it, S.O is for specific questions.

Comment: for what its worth i query  thousands (can be 100k) of buffered rows, when the db server is on the same network the return is near instant, perhaps you sould benchmark it.

Comment: I was specific. 1 MySQL server, and many loadbalanced virtual PHP nodes (on the same network) that are running large queries (thousands of rows) and should be able to immediately begin acting on that data without waiting for the whole thing to buffer. From your reply it sounds like you recommend buffered queries because the wait time is small enough it's not worth worrying about. I will benchmark it and see.

Comment: When I benchmarked it it doesn't seem to make a difference whether I use buffered queries or unbuffered queries, and the wait time to begin working on the result set is nearly the same. In fact the buffered query was faster by a fraction of a second. But I'm worried I may have done something wrong in my test so I'm not sure what to think. I expected the unbuffered query to have been the faster one.

Comment: I realized the flaw in my benchmark test and I rewrote it. What I found is that in my test it's many times faster to access the first row of the result set using an unbuffered query than using a buffered one. However, copying all of the rows into an array is significantly faster with the buffered query than the unbuffered one so that any gain you had from using an unbuffered query is lost. So neither solution is ideal it seems.

Comment: However if you are only copying a limited number of rows and then calling $mysqli->free_result() it evens out, but the buffered query still wins marginally.

Comment: But if I use $mysqli->close() after copying the limited number of rows, the unbuffered query wins significantly.

Answer (score 1):

> I do want it to buffer the results on the client so that MySQL isn't being held up longer than it has to

MySQL is quite capable of handling simultaneous connections—and indeed, simultaneous operations from those simultaneous connections.  That is, pretty much, one of the main *raisons d'être* of an RDBMS.

In order to prevent conflicts when simultaneous operations act on the same underlying data, MySQL will from time to time "lock" parts of the database for the exclusive use of one connection; however, once it begins transmitting results to the client, any locks that were acquired for that statement's execution will already have been released.  Thus MySQL will *never* be "held up" by a client that does not immediately load the entire resultset into a buffer.

So, on to your specific questions:

1. > Do buffered queries in MySQL/PHP really buffer the whole result set before PHP is allowed to begin using the results?

   Yes.
2. > And do unbuffered queries really use no buffering at all so that MySQL server is constantly waiting for PHP to request the next result before it is sent to the client?

   Pretty much.  The MySQL client library (in C) will perform *some* buffering, but only in order to perform network operations efficiently.
3. > If this is true, why isn't there a way to begin using the results immediately and yet still buffer the results to take the load off of MySQL?

   There is very little "load" on MySQL from an unbuffered query—sure, it has to keep a connection open and hold the resultset in memory, but that's rarely a very big concern.